# SQL Server duplicate inserts

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-insert, duplicates

I have a project (with c# and SQLServer), that it should run on multiple clients and each client should communicate with a central SQL Server. All of the clients and the server are on the same local network.
Everything is ok, but... in some cases, when a insert query runs on a client, multiple duplicate records insert into sql server. This problem occurs rarely.
Below is the query. The query runs when a form is filled and a button click event trigers.

```
public static int insertSick(string firstname,string lastname,string mobile,string address)
    {
        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(getConnectionString()))
        {
            string sql = "insert into TSick (Firstname,Lastname,MobileNumber,Address) values
                    (@fname,@lname,@mobile,@address)";

            connection.Open();
            SqlTransaction tran = connection.BeginTransaction();
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection, tran);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("fname", firstname);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("lname", lastname);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("mobile", mobile);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("address", address);

            int nRecord = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            tran.Commit();
            return nRecord;
        }
    }
private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
          // check the text fields and validate them
          insertSick(firstname,lastname,mobile,address);
    }
```

The table is as below:

```
TSick :
     - ID --> this column is an incremental identity
     - Firstname
     - Lastname
     - Mobilenumber
     - Address
```

Can someone tell me why in some cases instead of a single record multiple records inserted? How to solve? Do you think that it is a network related problem?

Thanks

Comment: If you have an IDENTITY column then you have two different records. But could you post the actual code that writes these data to your database?

Comment: Could it be that the user clicked the button multiple times? Are the text fields cleared after each db operation?

Comment: going to be tough to assist without any of the relevant C# code.  Can you update the question with more of your code?  I doubt it is a network related problem

Comment: I think that this is not a click problem. because i saw a record that inserted 12 times.!!!

Comment: The code was updated.

Comment: It can't be a network issue between the application and the database; such an issue would cause the transaction to rollback rather than commit.  Insertstick appears to be being called (and complete successfully) multiple times.  Add some logging to your code, writing as much information as you can get hold of to a file.  Without debugging techniques you're just guessing.

Answer (score 0):

It's almost certainly that the user clicks the button twice.  You should disable the button as the first thing in your click event handler, and then enable it again at the appropriate time; what constitutes the "appropriate time" is up to you to decide.

Comment: Thanks. I'll test this solution and feedback the result.

Answer (score 0):

Before from the insertion of data in table you can do  validation of data whether data is duplicate or not.

First check which column is unique in your table, on the basis of unique column you can check the data otherwise make a composite key(if there is no unique column) in the table and verify the data before from insertion. If a data is duplicate through a message to user.

Comment: I can solve the problem with this kind of solutions. But there is a question in my mind. Why a record (in some cases) inserted multiple times????

Comment: It is happening because user clicks the button multiple times. Disable the click button after first click.  But the best option is do validation before from insertion if any duplicate data will come table will not allow the data and you can though a error to user.